# What is the point of having two different names for the same parameter?

Tags: swift, function, parameters

```
func mapEachElement (inArray arr: [Int],  withFunc aFunc: (Int))
```

Why would there be "inArray and then "arr"...what's the point?

Same for "withFunc and "aFunc", it makes it more code complicated and also messier to read, why are they even used?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

inArray is external name which the caller of the function should use when passing parameters. arr is the internal name which the function implementer uses in the implementation to refer to the parameter. You don't have to supply external name.It makes it more readable. It is more like to make swift function names and parameters readable as Objective-C functions are.

Comment: so inArray is passed from the argument in the function call to the function?

Comment: Thank you so much, Its very clear for me now. You're awesome!!

Comment: Glad, my explanation helped.

Comment: part of this function header confuses me a little, here is the part: func mapEachElement   (inArray arr:  [Int],   withFunc  aFunc:  (Int) -> Int) ->  [Int] {

Comment: The types are what confuse me, the (int)'s and the [int]

Comment: That's passing a closure (code block) as a parameter. Read up on closures in the Apple Swift language book. It explains it pretty well.

Comment: The part before -> says it's a closure that accepts an int as an argument, and the part after -> says the closure returns and array of type int.

Comment: I did read up on it and it says that basically this function is accepting a funciton of type int that has a return type of int and then this  function returns an array of type int......oh lol I see now @DuncanC

Comment: functions and closures are types in swift. They can be stored in a variable and passed around.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sold on the issue of having different internal and external names either.

Having or not having external names makes sense to me.

`object.BeepXTimes(6)` doesn't need an external name for it's parameter because the function name implies the meaning of the parameter.

The rationale, I think, is that sometimes the naming of a function's external parameters is phrased to make sense to the caller in a sentence:

```
someView.animateInWithDuration(0.25, withTimingFunction: .easeIn)
```

The external name `withTimingFunction` makes the function call read like a sentence, but `withTimingFunction` makes a lousy internal parameter name. You would probably want your parameter name to be just `timingFunction`. Having separate internal and external parameter names lets you do that.

For me, though, the extra complexity this requires in the function definition doesn't seem worth it. The good news is that the default is to create parameters using the same name for both internal and external parameter names, so the standard syntax is simple and easy to read.

Comment: yes the # before the parameter name, that is much more efficient and easier to see also, thanks a lot!

Comment: The # before the parameter name is deprecated in Swift 2.0 and produces a warning.

Comment: Sorry. I was referring to Swift 2.0. I wish Apple would release Swift 2.0 so we could only have to worry about a single syntax.

Answer (score 0):

These are **internal** and **external** parameter names.

Just like in Obj-C, you might have

```
- (void)calculateFoo:(id)foo withBar:(id)bar ...

[object calculateFoo:var1 withBar:var2];
```

in Swift, we use

```
func calculateFoo(foo: AnyObject, withBar bar: AnyObject) ...

object.calculateFoo(var1, withBar: var2)
```

The internal names `foo` and `bar` are only accessible inside the function/method. The external names provide the argument *labels* which you use to call the function.

In your case, you need to use the *internal* name `nibBundle`. That's the one accessible inside the function body.